# Merging into one DataContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using asp.net MVC 5 and i have two context at the moment and it giving me problems when I deploy my application in Azure because I'm using a Repository Pattern so I want merging it into one DataContext.

this is my Applicationcontext in Identity Models class

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("SurgeryConn")
    {
    }
}
```

this is my DataContext

public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext, IDbContext
    {

```
    public DataContext()
        : base("SurgeryConn")
    {

    }

    //#region Properties


    public DbSet<Supplier.Supplier> Supplier { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Dispensary.Dispensary> Dispensary { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Biochemistry> Biochemistry { get; set; }


    //#endregion

    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
```

Comment: Just move the DbSets and methods into the first context.

Answer (score 0):

move DbSets to first context and if you using reposiotry pattern you might wanna put IDContext on first context as follows:

```
 public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>,IDbContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("SurgeryConn")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Supplier.Supplier> Supplier { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Dispensary.Dispensary> Dispensary { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Biochemistry> Biochemistry { get; set; }

  public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
}
```